# What is this Delphi Setup error and how do I fix it?

Tags: delphi

I want to Install Delphi Community Edition, but then this error shows up when installing Interbase 2020 developer edition:

[image]

Comment: rename 
C:\ProgramData\{05500BA0-5731-46FD-9326-FA79A36E6D46} to something else, then try again

Answer (score 0):

After I closed the error window it automatically opened Delphi as normal, but I couldn't create or open applications to work with in Delphi - because of the missing files - it would just show some other error until I just downloaded some patch it optionally listed right on the screen: [Click here to see Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NiSf7.png)

After I downloaded the patch and my Delphi was fully up to date, everything worked as normal. I hope this helps others.